# jQuery .parent() does not work

Tags: jquery, html, parent

Why [the following code](http://jsfiddle.net/TCZV3/) fails with:

`Error: class_a_jquery_objects[0].parent is not a function`

?

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class='a b'></div>
    <div class='b c'></div>
    <div class='c a'></div>
</div>    
<div id='log'></div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    var class_a_jquery_objects = $(".a");

    $("#log").append(class_a_jquery_objects.length + "<br />");
    $("#log").append(class_a_jquery_objects[0] + "<br />");
    $("#log").append(class_a_jquery_objects[0].parent() + "<br />");
});
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

class_a_jquery_objects[0] is a DOM element and not a jQuery object. You can't call jQuery methods with it. You need to first wrap it in a jQuery object:

```
$(class_a_jquery_objects[0]).parent()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap it with JQuery object

```
   $("#log").append($(class_a_jquery_objects[0]).parent() + "<br />");
```